# What does ImageDataGenerator.fit() function does in Keras Image preprocessing?

Tags: keras, image-preprocessing, data-augmentation

There is ImageDataGenerator.flow() function, in which we pass our training images and it returns augmented images. But what does ImageDataGenerator.fit() function does?

Answer (score 2):

For some transformations such as centering or scaling, the ImageDataGenerator needs statistics on the data such the feature-wise mean, standard deviation etc. The `fit()` method collects these statistics. This API is similar to how the preprocessing functions in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing) work.